# query returning slow response while fetching data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I have table with 20k more row candidate data in which i have saved CV in html format(Complete doc. file through text area editor).Trying to search in that column and some other column returning very slow response and some time showing timeout error.

**Here is the query:**

```
SELECT `candidate`.`id`, `candidate`.`email`, `candidate`.`fname`, `candidate`.`lname`, `candidate`.`id` as `can_id`, `candidate`.`update_date` AS `updated_at`, DATE_FORMAT(candidate.dob, '%d-%m-%Y') AS dob, `candidate`.`gender`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT candidate_experience.functional_area_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS can_functional_area, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT candidate_experience.industry_type_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS can_industry_type_name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT qualification_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS qualification_name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT candidate_key_skills.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS skill, `candidate_desired_job`.`current_location`, `candidate_desired_job`.`total_experiance`, `candidate_desired_job`.`prefered_location`, `candidate_desired_job`.`notice_period`, IFNULL(candidate_desired_job.expected_salary, 'N') AS expected_salary
FROM `candidate`
LEFT JOIN `candidate_key_skills` ON `candidate_key_skills`.`candidate_id` = `candidate`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `candidate_qualification` ON `candidate_qualification`.`candidate_id` = `candidate`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `candidate_desired_job` ON `candidate_desired_job`.`candidate_id` = `candidate`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `candidate_experience` ON `candidate_experience`.`candidate_id` = `candidate`.`id`
WHERE   (
`name` LIKE '%PHP%' ESCAPE '!'
 )
AND   (
`prefered_location` LIKE '%Ahmedabad%' ESCAPE '!'
 )
AND `total_experiance` >= '-1'
AND `total_experiance` <= '40'
AND `expected_salary` >= '0'
AND `expected_salary` <= '500000'
AND   (
`candidate_experience`.`industry_type_name` LIKE '%Accommodation and Food Services%' ESCAPE '!' 
 )
OR  `carrier_summary` LIKE '%PHP%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `carrier_summary` LIKE '%Ahmedabad%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `carrier_summary` LIKE '%Accommodation and Food Services%' ESCAPE '!' 
AND `candidate`.`id` >0
GROUP BY `candidate_key_skills`.`candidate_id`, `candidate_desired_job`.`id`
ORDER BY `candidate_desired_job`.`id` DESC
```

**Table Schema :**

[image]

**Data format:**

[image]

I have tried Ajax also but still it takes time.

Comment: Edit your question and show the schema of the tables (including indexes)

Comment: Why are you using ```ESCAPE '!'``` in your like clauses and not using it as the escape character in your literal strings?

Comment: I have added table schema and data format. @SloanThrasher

Comment: Have you added an index for `candidate_id`?

Comment: You added the schema for one of the tables. What about the others? Do you have a full text index on the column you're testing ```carrier_summary```? If not, that's a part of why your query is running slowly.